# how to get the two collections data into one output in mongodb using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, collections

These are my two collections in MongoDB, and when I use `$lookup` to get the details my result comes with a nested array. I need the result to be like below:

#### First collection

```
locations = [{
  locationName : "DC",
  locationCategoryCode:"1"
}, {
  locationName : "New York",
  locationCategoryCode:"1"
}, {
  locationName : "Utah",
  locationCategoryCode:"2"
}]
```

#### Second collection

```
locationCategory = [{
  locationCategoryCode:"1",
  locationCategoryName:"history"
}, {
  locationCategoryCode:"2",
  locationCategoryName:"nature"
}]
```

#### Result

```
result = [{
  locationName : "DC",
  locationCategoryName:"history"
}, {
  locationName : "NewYork",
  locationCategoryName:"history"
}]
```

Any solution for this, please and thank you?

Answer (score 1):

Using aggregation you could:

- $lookup the category, returning an array
- $addFields to add the category name to the top level document
- $project to remove the added array and the location code

```
db.locations.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "locationCategory",
      localField: "locationCategoryCode",
      foreignField: "locationCategoryCode",
      as: "locationCategory"
  }},
  {$addFields: {
      locationCategoryName: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$locationCategory.locationCategoryName",0]
      }
  }},
  {$project: {
      locationCategory: 0,
      locationCategoryCode: 0
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AFZfpGJhRuG)

Comment: this helped me to develop the end result that I was looking for. really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can find the associated `locationCategoryName` of each `location` by searching `locationCategory` using the `locationCategoryCode`.

```js
const locations = [{
  locationName: "DC",
  locationCategoryCode: "1"
}, {
  locationName: "New York",
  locationCategoryCode: "1"
}, {
  locationName: "Utah",
  locationCategoryCode: "2"
}];

const locationCategory = [{
  locationCategoryCode: "1",
  locationCategoryName: "history"
}, {
  locationCategoryCode: "2",
  locationCategoryName: "nature"
}];

const result = locations
  .map(({ locationName, locationCategoryCode }) => ({
    locationName,
    locationCategoryName: locationCategory.find(({ locationCategoryCode: curr }) =>
      curr === locationCategoryCode).locationCategoryName
  }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```